# SQL ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list

Tags: sql, oracle

i'm creating a few tables which look like this

```
CREATE TABLE sickness
(
sickness_id     number(2),
sickness_name   varchar2(20),
PRIMARY KEY (sickness_id)
);

CREATE TABLE cover
(
cover_needed char(1) NOT NULL,
employee_id number(3),
responsibilities varchar2(50),
notes varchar2(50),
PRIMARY KEY (cover_needed, employee_id)
);
```

this works fine then when i try to make a parent table (see below), i get the error.

```
ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list
```

i have however narrowed it down to the last line but i can not for the life of me figure it out, thank you

```
CREATE TABLE absences
(
absences_id  number(2) NOT NULL,
manager_id number(3),
employee_id number(3) NOT NULL,
absence_name varchar2(15) NOT NULL,
sickness_id number(2),
date_from date NOT NULL,
date_to date NOT NULL,
length number(2) NOT NULL,
description varchar2(40),  
authorised_by_manager char(1) NOT NULL,
cover_needed char(1) NOT NULL,
half_day char(1) NOT NULL,

PRIMARY KEY (absences_id, manager_id, employee_id),

FOREIGN KEY (sickness_id)  REFERENCES sickness (sickness_id),
FOREIGN KEY (cover_needed) REFERENCES cover    (cover_needed)
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you define `cover`:

```
CREATE TABLE cover (
    . . .
    **PRIMARY KEY (cover_needed, employee_id)**
);
```

You have a composite primary key.  Foreign key references need to reference both keys . . . and in the same order.

So:

```
FOREIGN KEY (cover_needed, employee_id)
    REFERENCES cover (cover_needed, employee_id)
```

I think your data structures and queries would be simpler if you used auto-generated numeric primary keys.  That would simplify the foreign key relationships and simplify the queries that connect tables.

Comment: my only thing is though in my erd i have my cover table connected to two tables which use different foreign keys, my employee_id is not a primary key for  the absences table, its for a different table which has a PFkey employee_id. if that makes sense

Comment: @SeanKhanna . . . No, your comment doesn't really make sense.  But it does emphasize why you should have a single column that identifies each *row* in a table, rather than composite primary keys.